# Backbone set method, pass a variable as the key?

Tags: javascript, function, backbone.js, set

Im trying to pass an argument which would dynamically set the key in the backbone `set` method.

I pass it as a string into the constructor of my function like this

`this.keyStat('points', 1)`

That passes `points`, but when I set the model it creates the attribute `stat` not recognizing it as a variable.

```
keyStat: function(stat, number) {
    var addStat = parseInt(this.model.get(stat)) + number;       
    console.log(this.model.set({stat: addStat}));
}
```

I am trying to build this function so that I dont have to repeat a lot of code and bloat my project, but I am not sure how I can pass that into the `set` method so that it recognizes my argument.

My question is how do I pass an argument/variable to the backbone `set` methods key?

Comment: The docs cover this: ["You may also pass individual keys and values."](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set).

Comment: yeah I actually read that I wasnt really thinking, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set method can take a key as a first argument and value as a second (unless first argument is an object)

```
keyStat: function(stat, number) {
  var addStat = parseInt(this.model.get(stat)) + number;       
  console.log(this.model.set(stat, addStat));
}
```

Comment: Wow I was so close I did something like your answer but I did it in a weird way, I thought by not passing it as an object would work but since I think I added the key and value then passed that in I messed it up and gave up on that idea. The above works thanks!